# Can't go to children path from buttons in parent path

Tags: javascript, user-interface, vue.js, routes, frontend

I'm a data scientist and totally new to frontend, but my boss wants me to build a UI so here we are. I'll try my best to explain my problem, so pardon me for my unprofessional wording.

I'm using Vue.js. And I have a parent `home/settings` with a menu of sub-pages there. When I click on the menu, I want to go to `home/settings/page1`, but instead it goes to `home/page1`.

I can manually type in `home/settings/page1` and from there the page navigates to other sub-pages fine, but if I'm in `home/settings`, it substitutes `settings` with `page`, and of course there's nothing there.

`router.js` looks like this:

```
Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: { base: Home },
    },
    {
      path: '/Settings',
      components: { base: Settings },
      children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          components: { settingsMain: SettingsPage1 },
        },
        {
          path: 'page1',
          components: { settingsMain: SettingsPage1 },
        },
        {
          path: 'page2',
          components: { settingsMain: SettingsPage2 },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
})
```

The component in `Settings` looks like this:

```
<template>
  <fd-menu @select="goToPage">
    <fd-menu-list>
      <fd-menu-item value="1">
        Setting 1
      </fd-menu-item>
      <fd-menu-item value="2">
        Setting 2
      </fd-menu-item>
    </fd-menu-list>
  </fd-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    goToPage(item)
    {
      this.$router.push('page' + item.value)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

`router.push` requires the full navigation path to match routes like `<router-link>`. Try setting the full child path.

`this.$router.push('/settings/page' + item.value)`